# Need a KVM that supports advanced mice, keyboards, and other peripherals

Tags: keyboard, mouse, product-rec, kvm-switch

I've used a number of KVMs and found a great variation in performance with mice. Some seem to support wireless mice and others don't (or worse mouse pointer gets stuck occasionally and drives you mad!). What brands or models are known to work well with advanced or wireless mice? Does anyone have experience with other peripherals like webcams, storage etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webcams and storage will not be supported (the devices must be kind-of stateless for KVM to work).